# How can I get the resolution (width and height) for a video file from a linux command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, video, ffmpeg, resolution

I've been digging through the mplayer/mencoder and ffmpeg documentation and I can't seem to come up with **anything**. I'm not especially picky as to the output format as I can use a regular expression to pull it out, I just can't seem to get the data in the first place.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/249828/command-to-see-media-file-info-in-terminal

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) has a command line version and provides the dimensions together with *tons* of other information.

Comment: This is useful. For a more targeted approach see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43443097/3816360) :-)

Comment: mediainfo works for me. I was looking for the framerate of a Matroska file inside Linux Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 117):

Use [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) (part of FFmpeg toolkit)

example:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams ~/Movies/big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4
```

output:

```json
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "Main",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "1/50",
            "codec_tag_string": "avc1",
            "codec_tag": "0x31637661",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720,
            "coded_width": 1280,
            "coded_height": 720,
            "has_b_frames": 0,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "16:9",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 31,
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "refs": 1,
            "is_avc": "1",
            "nal_length_size": "4",
            "r_frame_rate": "25/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "25/1",
            "time_base": "1/12800",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 378368,
            "duration": "29.560000",
            "bit_rate": "1032960",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "nb_frames": "739",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "creation_time": "1970-01-01 00:00:00",
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "VideoHandler"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "aac",
            "codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)",
            "profile": "LC",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_time_base": "1/48000",
            "codec_tag_string": "mp4a",
            "codec_tag": "0x6134706d",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 6,
            "channel_layout": "5.1",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/48000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 1419264,
            "duration": "29.568000",
            "bit_rate": "383960",
            "max_bit_rate": "416704",
            "nb_frames": "1386",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "creation_time": "1970-01-01 00:00:00",
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "SoundHandler"
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "/Users/farsheed/Movies/big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4",
        "nb_streams": 2,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2",
        "format_long_name": "QuickTime / MOV",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "29.568000",
        "size": "5253880",
        "bit_rate": "1421504",
        "probe_score": 100,
        "tags": {
            "major_brand": "isom",
            "minor_version": "512",
            "compatible_brands": "isomiso2avc1mp41",
            "creation_time": "1970-01-01 00:00:00",
            "encoder": "Lavf53.24.2"
        }
    }
}
```

See documentation for more info.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i video.mpg` is also an option.

Comment: @Ben `ffprobe` does the same exact thing except it doesn't return an error code (and expect you to provide encoding options)

Comment: do you happen to have the bean classes for the fields for ffprobe show_streams command? (I would like to serialize)

Comment: You can use `jq` to pipe in the width too. `ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams <PATH TO FILE> | jq -r '.streams[0].width'`

Comment: @JulioCorzo I've found in my work that stream[0] isn't always the video stream.

Comment: `ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams video.mp4  | jq '.streams[0] | (.width|tostring) + "x" + (.height|tostring)'`

Answer (score 93):

Use `ffprobe`:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 input.mp4
```

Example output:

```
1280x720
```

See [FFprobe Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) and [FFmpeg Wiki: FFprobe Tips](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips) for more info.

Comment: What are all the parameters?

Answer (score 47):

## Using exiftool

run the command

```
exiftool VIDEOFILE
```

The output you get is similar to this:

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 9.76
File Name                       : gource2.mkv
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 2010 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2015:01:07 14:16:22-06:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2015:01:07 14:16:22-06:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2015:01:07 14:16:22-06:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
File Type                       : MKV
MIME Type                       : video/x-matroska
EBML Version                    : 1
EBML Read Version               : 1
Doc Type                        : matroska
Doc Type Version                : 4
Doc Type Read Version           : 2
Timecode Scale                  : 1 ms
Muxing App                      : libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.1
Writing App                     : mkvmerge v7.4.0 ('Circles') 64bit built on Dec 17 2014 11:31:10
Duration                        : 2:35:09
Date/Time Original              : 2015:01:07 20:14:22Z
Video Codec ID                  : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Video Frame Rate                : 60
Track Language                  : und
Image Width                     : 1280
Image Height                    : 1024
Display Width                   : 1280
Display Height                  : 1024
Track Number                    : 2
Track Type                      : Audio
Audio Codec ID                  : A_DTS
Default Duration                : 10.666666 ms
Audio Sample Rate               : 48000
Audio Channels                  : 6
Image Size                      : 1280x1024
```

## Using ffmpeg/ffprobe

run the command

```
ffprobe VIDEOFILE
```

alternatively:

```
ffmpeg -i VIDEOFILE
```

The output you get is similar to this:

```
ffprobe version 2.1.6 Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 29 2014 12:07:56 with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC) 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libcelt --enable-libdc1394 --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      52. 48.101 / 52. 48.101
  libavcodec     55. 39.101 / 55. 39.101
  libavformat    55. 19.104 / 55. 19.104
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 90.100 /  3. 90.100
  libavresample   1.  1.  0 /  1.  1.  0
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'gource2.mkv':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2015-01-07 20:14:22
  Duration: 02:35:09.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1811 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 1280x1024, SAR 1:1 DAR 5:4, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536 kb/s (default)
```

## Using mplayer

run the command

```
mplayer -really-quiet -ao null -vo null -identify -frames 0 VIDEOFILE
```

The output you get is similar to this:

```
ID_VIDEO_ID=0
ID_AUDIO_ID=0
ID_AID_0_LANG=eng
ID_CLIP_INFO_NAME0=creation_time
ID_CLIP_INFO_VALUE0=2015-01-07 20:14:22
ID_CLIP_INFO_N=1
ID_FILENAME=gource2.mkv
ID_DEMUXER=lavfpref
ID_VIDEO_FORMAT=H264
ID_VIDEO_BITRATE=0
ID_VIDEO_WIDTH=1280
ID_VIDEO_HEIGHT=1024
ID_VIDEO_FPS=60.000
ID_VIDEO_ASPECT=0.0000
ID_AUDIO_FORMAT=8193
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=1536000
ID_AUDIO_RATE=48000
ID_AUDIO_NCH=6
ID_START_TIME=0.00
ID_LENGTH=9309.70
ID_SEEKABLE=1
ID_CHAPTERS=0
ID_VIDEO_CODEC=ffh264
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=1536000
ID_AUDIO_RATE=48000
ID_AUDIO_NCH=6
ID_AUDIO_CODEC=ffdca
ID_EXIT=EOF
```

## Using mediainfo

run the command

```
mediainfo VIDEOFILE
```

The output you get is similar to this:

```
General
Unique ID                                : 311795358270161665158539797930749663166 (0xEA919A09196F0CAEF4E1B4FEB72B17BE)
Complete name                            : gource2.mkv
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 4 / Version 2
File size                                : 1.96 GiB
Duration                                 : 2h 35mn
Overall bit rate                         : 1 811 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2015-01-07 20:14:22
Writing application                      : mkvmerge v7.4.0 ('Circles') 64bit built on Dec 17 2014 11:31:10
Writing library                          : libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.1

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Baseline@L4.2
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Bit rate                                 : 266 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 1 024 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 5:4
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Writing library                          : x264 core 138 r2363 c628e3b
Encoding settings                        : cabac=0 / ref=1 / deblock=0:1:1 / analyse=0:0 / me=dia / subme=0 / psy=1 / psy_rd=0.40:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=0 / weightp=0 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=0 / intra_refresh=0 / rc=crf / mbtree=0 / crf=22.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=0
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : DTS
Format/Info                              : Digital Theater Systems
Mode                                     : 16
Format settings, Endianness              : Big
Codec ID                                 : A_DTS
Duration                                 : 2h 35mn
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 509 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Bit depth                                : 24 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 1.64 GiB (83%)
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
```

## time summary

```
exiftool
    real    0m0.089s
    user    0m0.081s
    sys     0m0.008s
mplayer
    real    0m0.050s
    user    0m0.034s
    sys     0m0.017s
ffprobe/ffmpeg
    real    0m0.017s
    user    0m0.011s
    sys     0m0.007s
mediainfo
    real    0m0.029s
    user    0m0.025s
    sys     0m0.004s
```

YMMV, but ffprobe is the fastest followed by mediainfo then mplayer and finally exiftool

```
ffprobe < mediainfo < mplayer < exiftool
```

Comment: mediainfo works for me. I was looking for the framerate of a Matroska file inside Linux Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. Thank you so much!

Comment: `exiftool -s3 -ImageSize VIDEOFILENAME` for _just_ the image dimensions as `123x456`

Answer (score 14):

To return **only** the Width and Height [mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) is an excellent tool.

mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Width%" Videofile && mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Height%" Videofile will do exactly that, no more, no less, for a [vast array of supported video files.](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Support/Formats)

There is a long list of useful `Inform=` parameters which you can obtain with the command `mediainfo --Info-Parameters`

If you want the output in standard WidthXHeight format use `Width=$(mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Width%" Video.File)&& Height=$(mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Height%" Video.File)&&echo $Width"X"$Height`

There's a bash script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46565234/3816360) that you could easily modify to meet your needs.

Or as [darkdragon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3779655/darkdragon) mentioned in [a comment recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684015/how-can-i-get-the-resolution-width-and-height-for-a-video-file-from-a-linux-co/43443097#comment109322164_43443097) `mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Width%X%Height%" Videofile`

Sources:

[Adding an Overlay Using FFMPEG With Minimal Re-Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180671/adding-an-overlay-using-ffmpeg-with-minimal-re-encoding/46565234#46565234)

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/mediainfo.1.html

[whiptail: How to redirect output to environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970180/whiptail-how-to-redirect-output-to-environment-variable)

[How to concatenate string variables in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-to-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash)

Comment: Thanks. This answer really helped me.

Comment: I'm glad it helped!

Comment: One can also do `mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Width%X%Height%" Video.file` directly.

Answer (score 5):

Try midentify.sh (TOOLS/midentify.sh in the source code tree of MPlayer).

It will show information in a parseable format:

```
$ ./midentify.sh /data/myvid.flv 
ID_VIDEO_ID=0
ID_AUDIO_ID=1
ID_FILENAME=/data/myvid.flv
ID_DEMUXER=lavfpref
ID_VIDEO_FORMAT=VP6F
ID_VIDEO_BITRATE=0
ID_VIDEO_WIDTH=640
ID_VIDEO_HEIGHT=480
```

[,,,]

Comment: In my system (Linux mint), I had to do `sudo apt install mplayer`, and then `/usr/share/mplayer/midentify.sh video.avi`

Answer (score 3):

If you are just interested in the resolution:

```
ffprobe -v error -of flat=s=_ -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height,width video.mkv
```

It works also on [Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). This is running right now on my PC to build an index of all files:

```
find //Q1207/Film -size +10000k -print -a -exec ./ffprobe.exe -v error -of flat=s=_ -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height,width \{\} \; > //Q1207/Film/index.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an "almost-one-liner" I've concocted around ffprobe for exactly this purpose. Works pretty well for me both on Linux and MacOS.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

B='[[:blank:]]'
D='[[:digit:]]'
ffprobe "$1" 2>&1 \
    | grep 'Stream.*Video.*fps' \
    | sed "s/^.*$B\($D$D$D*x$D$D$D*\).*$/\1/"
```

Answer (score -2):

The good ol' "file" utility will often get the dimensions of a video file.

Comment: I tried it on a few and it was crazy unreliable. Seemed like it could only really handle mpeg files.

Answer (score -2):

If you are not a terminal freak just open the file in Handbrake. It reports the image dimensions along with the file name. Works with mkv files.

Comment: They're explicitly asking how to get this via the command line. There are likely reasons they want to do that, such as scripting. This doesn't offer an answer to this question (which I think we can conclude was effectively answered nearly a decade ago).