# Variable concatenation has strange result in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I am writing (my first) shell script, and, for flexibility would like to use variables. Here is a part of script I wrote following different examples searched:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
jar_path="/sbclocal/apps/blablabla"
echo $jar_path            # <- OK
echo ${jar_path}          # <- OK
echo $jar_path/jar        # <- /jarlocal/apps/blablabla
echo "$jar_path/jar"      # <- /jarlocal/apps/blablabla
echo ${jar_path}/jar      # <- /jarlocal/apps/blablabla
echo "${jar_path}/jar"    # <- /jarlocal/apps/blablabla
```

In the last line, I expect to get "/sbclocal/apps/blablabla/jar", but what I get is "/jarlocal/apps/blablabla"! So instead of concatenation, starting of the variable string is replaced with the constant part, which I expect in the end!

There is also more complex concatenation inside of the jar parameter, which gets broken in a way I can't figure out for sure, but I suppose the issue is the same.

What is wrong here please?

UPD: Edited to show different approaches I tried, all having the same result.

UPD: I have also tried with 2 variables, strange thing is that the first one is not shown, like it's empty, when I write something like

```
echo $var1$var2
echo ${var1}${var2}
echo ${var1}+${var2}
```

This is crazy, I think I will give up and use old plain copy-paste, as this will be much quicker.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-can-i-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash

Comment: Fredrik, this question is one of the sources I used, I don't see other way there, except the one that is stated to be specifically for Bash, with +. I use SH.

Comment: all your examples gives the correct result in `bash` as well as `dash`. On my machine /bin/sh is a symlink to bash. check with `ls -l /bin/sh`. What does it say on you machine and what version of the shell are you running?

Comment: ls shows: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Feb  7  2012 /bin/sh -> bash*
So it's bash also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To long to put as a comment...

```
$ ./var.sh 
/sbclocal/apps/blablabla
/sbclocal/apps/blablabla
/sbclocal/apps/blablabla/jar
/sbclocal/apps/blablabla/jar
/sbclocal/apps/blablabla/jar
/sbclocal/apps/blablabla/jar
```

As I said, your scrip works perfectly for me. Somethings to check:

First, change the shebang to `#!/bin/sh -x` to enable debugging and look at the output.

Secondly, run `file var.sh` to check the line endings. Expected result should be:

```
$ file var.sh 
var.sh: POSIX shell script text executable
```

Convert to unix-format using `dos2unix` or `fromdos`.

Comment: Fabulous! It really was because I created the file in Windows! What I did is just resaved it as "unix script file" (from Notepad++) and it works now!

Comment: @Kurtevich outch :-) Glad I could help. Different line-endings causes subtle or really weird errors as in this case...

Comment: Usually they cause an unknown command error or somesuch, but echo was happy to include the carriage return in the Windows EOL in the argument list it was displaying.