# Not able to append the new folder name to the existing path in UNIX scripting

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

This is the following code (while loop) in shell scripting

```
do
    echo "directory under is @ " ${dir} >>${DEBUG_LOG_FILE}
    BUP="$PS_HOME/${PSFT_SID}/${dir}";
    echo "backup folder created is1  :  ${BUP} " ${BUP}   >>${DEBUG_LOG_FILE}
    $BUP=${BUP}+"/ArchFolder"
    BUP1=${BUP}+"ArchFolder" (Since "/" is already in the BUP variable"
    echo "backup folder created is 2 :  ${BUP1} " ${BUP1}   >>${DEBUG_LOG_FILE}
        echo "backup folder created is 3 :  ${BUP} " ${BUP}   >>${DEBUG_LOG_FILE}
    mkdir -p ${BUP}

done
```

when I echo ${BUP} at the beginning I am getting as /psoft/PNRDP1/sqr/ as the output (directory structure)

My task : Trying to append **/ArchFolder** to the above output and later, trying to a create a Directory using the mkdir command as you see in the above code snippet

Some how I see **/ArchFolder** is not getting concatenating at the end "**/psoft/PNRDP1/sqr/**".

My question is 
1) Is there any mistake in concatenation technique.

2) Or instead of concatenate and use that variable in mkdir, shall i append the new Directory name in the mkdir and execute, will that work, if yes can any one show me the piece of code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate two variables in Bash is easy, see an example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-can-i-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash):

```
foo="Hello"
foo="$foo World"
echo $foo
> Hello World
```

But an easier solution, without needing an extra variable would be similar of what you have mentioned in the second question :

```
    mkdir -p "${BUP}/ArchFolder"
```

Comment: If you notice, there is already a "/" in the end, "$BUP output ", do I need to still add that / in the mkdir like what you gave

Comment: No, in that case, simply omit "/": `mkdir -p "${BUP}ArchFolder"`