# Bash variable concatenation fails inside loop

Tags: string, bash, variables, concatenation

Given the following statements:

```
ac_reg_ids="-1" #Starting value
(mysql) | while read ac_reg_id; do
    echo "$ac_reg_id" #variable is a result of a mysql query. Echoes a number.
    ac_reg_ids="$ac_reg_ids, $ac_reg_id" #concatenate a comma and $ac_reg_id, fails.
done
echo "ac_reg_ids: $ac_reg_ids" #echoes -1
```

Now according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4181721/1313143

Concatenation should work. Why doesn't it, though? What's different within the loop?

Just in case it could matter:

> > bash -version
>   > GNU bash, version 4.2.8(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

### Update

Output with set -eux:

```
+ echo 142
142
+ ac_reg_ids='-1, 142'
+ read ac_reg_id
```

Comment: It looks fine to me. Is that the exact code that fails, copy-and-pasted, not typed by hand, nothing added or removed?

Comment: @JohnKugelman yes, I copied it.

Comment: what version of bash are you using? I have just tried this using 4.2.24, and the output of your sample code is exactly what you would expect, if `ac_reg_id` variable is not set, last line prints `-1, `

Comment: Please run `set -eux` before that piece of code, run it again and paste output here.

Comment: @Alex I added version. It's a bit older than yours but I don't see how it could matter in such small difference.

Comment: @esauvisky I added the results to my answer.

Comment: Where did that `read` come from? You're probably clearing the variable `ac_reg_id`!

Comment: @esauvisky I added more context, however I don't think it could make a difference since the snippet is part of a bigger script where I'm using variables in the same way, just without concatenation, and the rest of it works. Edit: uh-oh. Seems like a didn't get "scope" quite well here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) would helpfully have pointed out, you're modifying ac_reg_ids in a subshell.

Rewrite it to avoid the subshell:

```
ac_reg_ids="-1" #Starting value
while read ac_reg_id; do
    echo "$ac_reg_id" 
    ac_reg_ids="$ac_reg_ids, $ac_reg_id"
done < <( mysql whatever )  # Redirect from process substution, avoiding pipeline
echo "ac_reg_ids: $ac_reg_ids"
```

Comment: I'll see if it does the trick. Thanks for pointing out that website, didn't know about it yet. Could you give more information about how "< <" works? I'm pretty new with bash.

Comment: There is no `< <`. There is `<` which redirects from a file as I'm sure you already know, and there's `<(cmd)` which expands to a filename which when read produces the output from `cmd`. Any variation on this, such as `<< (cmd)`, `<<(cmd)` or `< < cmd` is invalid.

Comment: Okay I got it now. Thank you.