# How do I append to an existing string variable inside a loop in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash script that downloads stock prices and appends them to a variable, which is then outputted:

```
#!/bin/bash

output=" "
for stock in GOOG AAPL
do
  price=$(curl -s "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$stock&f=l1")
  output+="$stock: $price "
done

echo "$output"
```

This script only displays  `AAPL: 524.896`, the last piece of data fetched. According to [whatswrongwithmyscript](http://www.whatswrongwithmyscript.com/), there isn't anything wrong with the script, and I thought I was following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2250199/2766558) properly. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15120052/2766558) discussed a similar problem (appending to a string variable inside a loop) and suggested a different method which I used like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

output=" "
for stock in GOOG AAPL
do
  price=$(curl -s "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$stock&f=l1")
  output="$output$stock: $price "
done

echo "$output"
```

The output is still the same. I'm using bash 4.2.45 on debian jessie x64.

#### More info

I echoed the result in a loop to debug, and from the first script, this is what I get:

```
 GOOG: 1030.42
 AAPL: 524.896
 AAPL: 524.896
```

And the second script gives the same thing:

```
 GOOG: 1030.42
 AAPL: 524.896
 AAPL: 524.896
```

Comment: What you're seeing, I think, is `curl` not getting a stock price for Google.  Have you echoed stock and price in the loop as a debugging measure?  If the second technique is not working correctly, then the problem is in the data.  The first should also work, but...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It looks like `curl` is fetching the data. See the edit; I echoed stock and price, and the data is being fetched correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I run your script and pipe the output to `od -c`, the result is illuminating:

```
0000000       G   O   O   G   :       1   0   3   0   .   4   2  \r    
0000020   A   A   P   L   :       5   2   4   .   8   9   6  \r      \n
0000040
```

So you can see that it IS in fact getting all the entries and concatenating them, but its ALSO getting CR characters (the `\r` in the od output), which causes them to print over the top of each other when you print the string.

You can pipe the output of `curl` to `tr -d '\r'` to strip off the problematic CRs:

```
price=$(curl -s "...." | tr -d '\r')
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `od` command, and that's super helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure that the problem is that curl is returning a carriage return and this is messing with the printing of both values.  If you redirect the output of the curl command to a file and view it in vi, you'll see it's created a DOS file.

This seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

output=""
for stock in GOOG AAPL
do
  price=$(curl -s "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$stock&f=l1" | tr -d '\r')
  output+="$stock $price\n"
done

echo -e "$output"
```