# How to add content from different sources on the same line in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am wondering if it is possible to add content as a single line from different sources. I used paste but it didn't work.

e.g.

```
x=1
paste echo hi awk NR=="'$x' file.txt echo bye
```

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-can-i-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo hi $(awk NR=="$x" file.txt) bye
```

or add more sources:

```
echo hi $(awk NR=="$x" file.txt) $(awk NR-1=="$x" file.txt) bye
```