# Concatenate string literals

Tags: linux, bash, string-concatenation, string-literals

I've seen a couple posts for this, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-can-i-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash), but none are helping me in my particular situation.

```
scriptsPath="/var/db/gbi/scripts/"
echo "$scriptsPathawesome.csv";
```

I would expect this to echo `/var/db/gbi/scripts/awesome.csv`

Instead I get `.csv`

Seems like it thinks I'm trying to reference a variable named `$scriptsPathawesome`. How can I concatenate the `$scriptsPath` variable to the `"awesome.csv"` string literal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to surround your variable with curly braces like so:

```
scriptsPath="/var/db/gbi/scripts/"
echo "${scriptsPath}awesome.csv";
```

Comment: I would also (or instead) use an explicit path separator, to make it clearer. `$scriptsPath/awesome.csv` is safe, since multiple consecutive separators are treated as a single instance.