# combine variablecontent with dataending in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I searched for my problem on google and found following solution:
[How to concatenate string variables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-can-i-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash)
would have been cool if it had been that easy, but apparently there must be an exception for my problem. I have a shell script with a variable which looks like following

```
#!/bin/bash
egrep "CN=$1/" index.txt|awk '{print $3}'
userpem="$3.pem"
openssl x509 -in $userpem -noout -text
```

unfortunately it just gives out *.pem*. Do you have any suggestions why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it just gives out ".pem" why :( ?

Because `$3` is interpreted as an argument that was passed to the script which is probably nothing.

You need to concatenate the output of the command you executed.  Say:

```
userpem=$(egrep "CN=$1/" index.txt|awk '{print $3}').pem
```

instead.  You might also want to refer to [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).