# Adding Strings Together Unix

Tags: string, unix

So I'm a Unix n00b and I'm trying to add two strings together. One of them is called `INSTRUMENT` and I want to prefix that with `"SA;"`. I tried doing this but I'm getting an error:

```
$"SA;"$INSTRUMENTID
```

**Error:**

> (ERROR) Unable to resolve expression : $"SA;"$INSTRUMENTID

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-can-i-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash

Try echo $SA$INSTRUMENT

Answer (score 0):

You write the variables after each other and prepend the $ sign to them. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
a="SA"
b="INSTRUMENTID"
c=$a$b
echo $c
```

This will print `SAINSTRUMENTID`