# Error opening existing directory using opendir in c++

Tags: c++, file, opendir

I am making use of opendir() as below to access a directory.

```
DIR *dp;
if((dp  = opendir(dir.c_str())) == NULL) {
    cout << "Error(" << errno << ") opening " << dir << endl;
    return errno;
}
```

However, I keep getting the error below, even though the directory exists.

```
Error(2) opening /path/to/folder/
```

I am able to get a list of file names when I do ls /path/to/folder

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that /path/to/folder is different from /path/to/folder/

Comment: Can you show me the output of: ls -l /path/to/folder/  ?

Comment: @Marius what are the caveats when one is choosing between the no-trailing-slash version and its (apparently fraternal) twin version?

Answer (score 2):

`errno` value 2 means `ENOENT` (it's an abbreviaton for Error NO ENTry) that is "*Directory does not exist, or name is an empty string*".
How do you define `dir` in your code?

```
std::string dir = "/path/to/folder/";
DIR* dp = opendir(dir.c_str());

if (dp == NULL) 
{
    std::cout << "Error(" << errno << ") opening " << dir << std::endl;
    perror("opendir");

    return errno;
}

closedir(dp);
```

---

**Update #1:**

Try to call you shell script:

```
main.sh folder/ foldername
```

Where `main.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                         
path="$1$2"
echo "$path"
ls -l "$path"
```

Comment: dir is an std::string passed as argument from the main program. Manually inputting ./program folder/foldername works, but when I use a script as such : script.sh folder/ foldername, which calls ./program $folder$foldername, it does not work yet it is the same string.

Comment: Do you run the shell script from the same folder as `program` is? I think it could be a mismatch between relative and absolute paths.

Comment: me again, what does `ls -l $folder$foldername` result in `script.sh`?

Comment: It results in "No such file or directory", however, when outputting the string in my C++ program right before opendir(), the strings are the same. I specify the absolute path (I tried both)

Comment: ls $folder works, but ls $folder$foldername does not work in the script. Doing ls for the foldername I want works in the terminal. How do get this to work in my script? It seems like concatenating the strings is causing the issue, though this seems to be the recommended way to do it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-can-i-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash

Comment: I have tried them all. ls to whatever string I concatenate gives me the same error

Comment: First line prints the path correctly, second line "No such file or directory". When I ls in terminal the first line's path, it works...I really don't know what is going on

Comment: Definitely just realized that I hadn't fixed something in my code, so the directory I was trying to get C++ to access didn't exist at the time... *facepalm*