# Pass multiple args from bash into python

Tags: python, string, bash, command-line-arguments

I have a short inline python script that I call from a bash script, and I want to have it handle a multi-word variable (which comes from `$*`). I expected this to just work:

```
#!/bin/bash

arg="A B C"
python -c "print '"$arg"'"
```

but it doesn't:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    print 'A
           ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Why?

Comment: `python -c "print \"$arg\""` works for me.

Comment: or even `python -c "print '$arg'"`

Comment: The syntax highlighting shows the problem :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would like to explain why your code doesn't work.

What you wanted to do is that:

```
arg="A B C"
python -c "print '""$arg""'"
```

Output:

```
A B C
```

The problem of your code is that `python -c "print '"$arg"'"` is parsed as `python -c "print '"A B C"'"` by the shell. See this:

```
arg="A B C"
python -c "print '"A B C"'"
#__________________^^^^^____
```

Output:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    print 'A

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Here you get a syntax error because the spaces prevent concatenation, so the following `B` and `C"'"` are interpreted as two different strings that are not part of the string passed as a command to python interpreter (which takes only the string following `-c` as command).

For better understanding:

```
arg="ABC"
python -c "print '"$arg"'"
```

Output:

```
ABC
```

Comment: Awsome explanation bro +1, but you shud have posted it a little early!

Comment: Can you clarify why `python -c "print '"A B C"'"` gives a SyntaxError? I'm not sure I follow. What happens to the spaces?

Comment: @Barry: For sure. The spaces prevent concatenation so the following `B` and `C"'"` are interpreted as two different strings that are not part of the string passed as a command to python interpreter (which takes only the string following `-c` as command). Is it more clear?

Comment: Argh! Bro ya take away my silver medal! :( Lool anyway the better answer deserved it and yours certainly deserves the accept. Cheers and all the best

Comment: @BhargavRao: Loool really apologize bro! Didn't mean to do that. Just wanted to add some clarifications to the OP's question :p I'm sure and hope you'll get it back sooner! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem bro! The correct answer should be on top. And it is. That is the way SO works. And you'll get a bronze soon ;)

Answer (score 16):

The  BASH script is wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash

arg="A B C"
python -c "print '$arg'"
```

And output

```
$ sh test.sh 
A B C
```

Note that to concatenate two string variables you don't need to put them outside the string constants

Comment: Found a nice resource on concatenating strings here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-can-i-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash