# Error in string Concatenation in Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, unix

I am beginner to Shell scripting.

I have used a variable to store value `A="MyScript"`. I tried to concatenate the string in subsequent steps `$A_new`. To my surprise it didn't work and `$A.new` worked.

Could you please help me in understanding these details?

Thanks

Comment: Does the info in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-can-i-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash) help?

Comment: @MichaelScarn though it was not I was looking for but thanks for sharing such nice information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of a variable can contain letters ( a to z or A to Z), numbers ( 0 to 9) or the underscore character ( _).

Shell does not require any variable declaration as in programming languages as `C` , `C++` or `java`. So when you write `$A_new` shell consider `A_new` as a variable, which you have not assigned any value therefore it comes to be null.

To achieve what you mentioned use as :
`${A}_new`

Its always a good practice to enclose variable names in braces after `$` sign to avoid such situation.

Answer (score 3):

Shell [variable names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_231) are composed of alphabetic characters, numbers and underscores.

> 3.231 Name
>
> In the shell command language, a word consisting solely of underscores, digits, and alphabetics from the portable character set. The first character of a name is not a digit.

So when you wrote `$A_new` the shell interpreted the underscore (and `new`) as part of the variable name and expanded the variable `A_new`.

A period is not valid in a variable name so when the shell parsed `$A.new` for a variable to expand it stopped at the period and expanded the `A` variable.

The `${A}` syntax is designed to allow this to work as intended here.

You can use any of the following to have this work correctly (in rough order of preferability):

1. `echo "${A}_new"`
2. `echo "$A"_new`
3. `echo $A\_new`

The last is least desirable because you can't quote the whole string (or the `\` doesn't get removed. So since you should basically always quote your variable expansions you would end up probably doing `echo "$A"\_new` but that's no different then point 2 ultimately so why bother.

Comment: This is exact explanation for your query.
Also you can specify explicitly by any of the mentioned ways :
      
1. ${A}_new

2. $A\\_new

Comment: Thank you @Etan for your detailed answer. It clears my doubt and concepts.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the underscore is the valid character in variable names.
Try this way:
    ${A}_new or "$A"_new

Comment: Ya. `$A_new`, in fact, is `${A_new}`.

Comment: You mean `${A}_new` not `{$A}_new`.

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh. I didn't get your statement Robin.