# Scripting username creation from text file?

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I'm really new at Bash and scripting in general.
I have to create usernames formed of first letter of first name followed by last name. To do it, I use a provided text file that looks like this:

```
doe,john
smith,mike
...
```

I declared the following variables:

```
fname=$(cut -d, -f2 "file.txt" | cut -c1)
lname=$(cut -d, -f1 "file.txt")
```

But how do I put the elements together to form the names **jdoe** and **msmith** ? I tried the methods I know to concatenate strings and vriables, but nothing works..

I think I found a method using **awk** that is supposed to work, but is there any other way to "concatenate" the elements of 2 lists?
Thank you

Comment: Is this a roundabout way of asking how to [concatenate string variables in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-can-i-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ed Morton's `awk`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30313293/45375) is simplest (and probably fastest), but since you asked for a different solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS=, read -r last first _; do
  username=${first:0:1}${last}
  echo "username: $username"
done < file.txt
```

- `IFS=, read -r last first _` reads the first 2 `,`-separated fields from each input line (`_` is a dummy variable that receives the rest of the input line, if any; `-r` prevents interpretation of `\` chars. in the input, which is usually what you want).
- `username=${first:0:1}${last}` concatenates the 1st char. of variable `$first`'s  value with variable `$last`'s value, simply by placing the two variable references next to each other.

  - `${first:0:1}` - extract `1` character from `$first` at position `0` - is an example of [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), specifically: [substring expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_expansion)
- `< file.txt` is an input redirection that sends `file.txt`'s contents via stdin to the `while` loop.

Comment: My pleasure; I was hoping you would read them, in addition to @geirha's helpful links (as opposed to submitting a copy & paste homework :)

Comment: Definitely didn't cut and paste. I want to get good at this, not just pass a class :) thanks again

Comment: Awesome; glad to hear it.

Answer (score 3):

There's a million ways to do it, this is simplest:

```
$ awk -F, '{print substr($2,1,1) $1}' file
jdoe
msmith
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks a bit too much like homework, so I'll just drop some hints.

To read the lastname and firstname into separate variables for each line of the file, see [BashFAQ 1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). It should not involve `cut`.

To grab the first character of a variable, see [BashFAQ 100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100).

Comment: It is a homework :)  I didn't know about BashFAQ, I'll check it out, thanks a lot!