# Concatenate two strings together and print in a shell script

Tags: string, shell, ubuntu

I would like to set a command in a bash script (Ubuntu) where I can concatenate two strings together and print them. For example:

```
Users/Desktop/File_
```

and

```
20_A
```

I would like a command that allows me to concatenate them, such as:

```
Users/Desktop/File_20_A
```

In R to do that I use the command `paste0`. Does that exist also in bash?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-can-i-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash

Comment: Thank you, this suggested post satisfied my request.

Answer (score 0):

The command you're looking for is called `echo`.  For example if you have two variables A and B:

```
echo "$A$B"
```