# String starts again after every variable [Bash]

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to use multiple variables in a string but after each variable the string starts again and overrides the beginning:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1="ABCDEFG"
var2="hi"
echo "${var1} ${var2}"
echo "$var1 $var2"
```

It should output

```
ABCDEFG hi
```

But both echos output

```
 hiDEFG
```

Also if I only use one variable and put text after the variable it still overrides...

**There is also an example here:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17862845/8363344

```
bla=hello
laber=kthx
echo "${bla}ohai${laber}bye"
```

This should output:

```
helloohaikthxbye
```

But it outputs:

```
byeikthx
```

**I'm starting the .sh with**

```
sudo bash path/bash.sh
```

But with sudo sh it does not work as well...

I use Ubuntu 16.04 (as a virtual machine)

Thanks
Dennis

Comment: This is strange. Can you past output the same command only from shell(not from script). #> echo "${var1} ${var2}"

Comment: Just tried it, in the shell it works just normal, outputs "ABCDEFG hi".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a carriage return character in your input string(s).

You can pipe your `echo`  to a `tr` command to remove it from output string:

```
 echo "${var1} ${var2}" | tr -d '\r'
```

Comment: This works, thanks!!
So how do I remove the carriage return character, or do I always have to pipe with tr :S ?

Comment: You can clean you script with sed(GNU sed): `sed -i 's/\x0D//g' script.sh`.