# Concatinating paths in bash (.sh) resolves in path with '$'\r''

Tags: string, bash, shell, path

I get a string from a command that lokos like the following:

```
part1=$(pip install numpy 2>&1)
```

part1 has stored some variable like: `c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-package`

Now I want to append "`numpy`" to it. To do so I tried it with:

```
part1+=/numpy
```

and every other solution listed here: 
[How to concatenate strings in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-to-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash)

However the output looks like this: `'c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages'$'\r''/numpy'`

What do I have to do to get rid of this effect?

I am using Windows10 and scripting .sh files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
part1="${part1/$'\r'}/numpy"
```

Here `"${part1/$'\r'}` replaces `\r` by an empty string. `$'\r'` is special bash construct to enter escape sequences.

Comment: Thank you that worked, can you may explain what you have done?(I assume it is some kind of regex that deletes the \r part?

Comment: I added an explanation in my answer.