# Adding multiple user inputs into one variable in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am fairly new to unix bash scripting and need to know if this is possible. I want to ask user for their input multiple times and then store that input in to one variable.

```
userinputs=   #nothing at the start

read string
<code to add $string to $userinputs>
read string
<code to add $string to $userinputs> #this should add this input along with the other input
```

so if the user enters "abc" when asked first time, it add's "abc" in $userinputs

then when asked again for the input and the user enters "123" the script should store it in the same $userinputs

this would make the $userinput=abc123

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way to concat two strings in Bash is:

```
new_string="$string1$string2"
```

`{}` are needed around the variable name only if we have a literal string that can obstruct the variable expansion:

```
new_string="${string1}literal$string2"
```

rather than

```
new_string="$string1literal$string2"
```

You can also use the `+=` operator:

```
userinputs=
read string
userinputs+="$string"
read string
userinputs+="$string"
```

Double quoting `$string` is optional in this case.

---

See also:

- [How to concatenate string variables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47666598/6862601)

Comment: can I use this in a while loop to keep asking for the user's input until they enter a certain character like * and all the users input are saved in just one variable?

Comment: Yes, @M.Azeem, you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatentate variables and store multiple strings in the same one like so:

```
foo=abc
echo $foo # prints 'abc'
bar=123
foo="${foo}${bar}"
echo $foo # prints 'abc123'
```

You can use the other variables, or the same variable, when assigning to a variable, e.g. `a="${a}123${b}"`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703) for more info.

You don't have to quote the strings you're assigning to, or do the `${var}` syntax, but learning when to quote and not to quote is a surprisingly nuanced art, so it's often better to be safe than sorry, and the `"${var}"` syntax in double quotes is usually the safest approach (see any of these links for more than you ever wanted to know: [1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) [2](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) [3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)).

Anyway, you should read into a temporary variable (read, by default, reads into `$REPLY`) and concatentate that onto your main variable, like so:

```
allinput=
read # captures user input into $REPLY
allinput="${REPLY}"
read
allinput="${allinput}${REPLY}"
```

Beware that the `read` command behaves very differently depending on supplied switches and the value of the `IFS` global variable, especially in the face of unusual input with special characters. A common "just do what I mean" choice is to empty out IFS via `IFS=` and use `read -r` to capture input. See the [`read` builtin documentation](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read) for more info.