# Can I evaluate expressions in the bash string interpolation?

Tags: linux, bash

I tried this:

```
aaa=10
echo "sdf sdfsd sd ${aaa+=1} sdf sdf "
```

And got back:

```
aaa=10
sdf sdfsd sd =1 sdf sdf
```

Does bash support doing this somehow?

Comment: `echo "sdf sdfsd sd =$((myvar+=1)) sdf sdf "` the equal sign before the arithmetic expansion must be added manually. @JohnKugelman

Comment: The OP doesn't want `=1`. They want `11`.

Comment: really just want to increment every iteration (whether the new value is returned immediately or in the succeeding loop).  += does what i want

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-to-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash/18041780#18041780

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use `$(( expression ))` for **arithmetic expansion**:

```
echo "sdf sdfsd sd $((myvar+=1)) sdf sdf "
                    ^^        ^^
```

Output (with a preceding variable assignment `myvar=0`):

```
sdf sdfsd sd 1 sdf sdf
```

The whole token `$(( expression ))` is expanded to the result of the expression after evaluation. So `echo $((1+2))` gives `3`.

There's another non-expanding version of expression evaluation, `(( expr ))`, which returns `true`/`false` depending on the evaluation of the expression (non--zero/zero).

From `man bash`:

> #### Arithmetic Expansion
>
> Arithmetic expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic expression and the substitution of the result. The format for arithmetic expansion is:
>
> ```
> $((expression))
> ```

You must use double parentheses, as single parentheses is used to capture output of a command:

```
a=$(echo "hahaha") # a is hahaha
a=$((1+2)) # a is 3
```

---

<sup>Thanks to @JohnKugelman for pointing out the name of the syntax and the manpage</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`${parameter+word}` is a special [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in Bash (also required by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)): it stands for "if *`parameter`* is unset, use nothing, else use the expansion of *`word`* instead".

There is a variation of the expansion with `:+` instead of `+` that uses the expansion of *`word`* if *`parameter`* is unset *or null*.

These are all the possible scenarios:

```
$ unset myvar
$ echo "${myvar+instead}"    # Unset: print nothing

$ myvar=
$ echo "${myvar+instead}"    # Null: print "instead"
instead
$ myvar=this
$ echo "${myvar+instead}"    # Set and not null: print "instead"
instead
$ unset myvar
$ echo "${myvar:+instead}"   # Unset: print nothing

$ myvar=
$ echo "${myvar:+instead}"   # Null: PRINT NOTHING (effect of :+)

$ myvar=this
$ echo "${myvar:+instead}"   # Set and not null: print "instead"
instead
```

In your case, because `myvar` is not null, you see `=1` instead.

What you want is [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) (see [iBug's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48487763/3266847)).

In Bash, you can use prefix increment for this:

```
$ var=10
$ for i in {1..3}; do echo "$((++var))"; done
11
12
13
```

POSIX [doesn't require](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) `++` and `--`, though.