# Add additional extention to specific file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, gzip

I'm trying to compress a file in a shell script and output its pre and post compression size. so far I take the file name as an argument, compress the file with gzip, and then grab the compressed size using the new file name. to get that new filename i am trying to add the .gz extension to the existing filename.

```
#!/bin/sh

#Name of the file input
NAME=$1

#Uncompressed size of the file input
UNCOMPRESSED=$(du -h $NAME | awk '{print $1}')

echo ""
echo "$NAME will be compressed using the gzip command."
echo ""
echo "gzip:"
echo "Uncompressed: $UNCOMPRESSED"

#Compress the file
GZNAME=$(gzip $NAME)

#Compressed size of the file input
COMPRESSED=$(du -h $GZNAME | awk '{print $1}')

echo "Compressed: $COMPRESSED"
```

How can i add the .gz extension to file name? i know this isnt right but maybe something like `NEW_NAME = $($NAME + ".gz")`
Everywhere i've seen is replacing the exisiting extension, but i wanna preserve the existing extension. so `$NAME --> file.txt` and `$NEW_NAME ---> file.txt.gz`
thanks!

Comment: What are you expecting the variable `GZNAME` to contain? You're assigning it the output of `gzip $NAME`, but that command will (most likely) produce no output, and `GZNAME` will be empty. That is, unless you have `gzip` aliased to something like `gzip -v`, but even then you will receive the whole line of output, not just the gzipped filename.

Comment: `new_name="${name}.gz"`?

Comment: [How to concatenate string variables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4181703/3776858)

Comment: @MikeHolt i shouldve named that better, perhaps renaming it to `GZIP` Would be more helpful. i essentially want it to just zip the original file. it shouldnt return anything, only create that .gz file

Comment: @Cyrus when i tried that i got `file.txt.gz: not found`

Comment: @jrdev I'm not referring to what you named it. It could be called `FOOBAR` if you want. I'm just curious why you're attempting to capture the output of the command `gzip $NAME` when it's not going to output anything. Then you try to use it later on in your `du -h $GZNAME ...` command, but since `$GZNAME` is empty, your command is really just `du -h | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: @MikeHolt now that i look at it thats really stupid.. i was assuming it would save the output ( size  &   filename) and i was trying to just get the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gzip` by default preserves the original extension and by default, adds `.gz` as the suffix.

```
$ echo "what" > 1.txt
$ gzip 1.txt
$ ls 1.txt.*
1.txt.gz
```

If you want anything other than `.gz` as your extension, use `-S` option:

```
$ gzip -S .zip 1.txt
$ ls 1.txt.*
1.txt.zip
```

Your assignment of `GZNAME=$(gzip $NAME)` is wrong. `$GZNAME` will be null for a successful compression. If you are using the default `.gz` extension, just use

```
gzip "$NAME" && GZNAME="${NAME}.gz"
```

Comment: hmm i didnt get any errors running that but when i tried to echo GZNAME i still got nothing. could it be because NAME has changed ? or is it stored as a string and not messed with when gzip runs? @iamauser

Comment: never mind i had the variable names mixed up. thanks! it worked with the very last command!