# Bash script : $x=$x+2 is not getting recognised

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

When I am executing the below script, I am getting the following error :-
 The script executes infintely and below line is printed everytime.
 "line 9: 1=1+2: command not found". Why?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Script 1 - Linux Scripting Book"
x=1

while [ $x -le 45 ]
do
        echo x : $x
        $x=$x+2
done

echo "End Of Script 1"

exit 0
```

Also if I change the `$x=$x+2` to `x+$x+2` then also I am getting the below error.

```
line 6: [: 1+2: integer expression expected
```

Same script when executed like this runs fine.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Script 1 - Linux Scripting Book"
x=1

while [ $x -le 45 ]
do
        echo x : $x
        let x=x+2
done

echo "End Of Script 1"

exit 0
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `declare -i x=1; x=$x+2; echo $x`

Comment: If I replace the $x=$x+2 with x=$x+2, then also I am getting error.

Comment: Do you fear the script will not end if you remove the exit 0? Do you know what it does?

Comment: About `+=`, have a look [there: How to concatenate string variables in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-to-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash/18041780#18041780) and read carefully about differences between `strings`, `integer` and `arrays`!

Comment: `expr` is a command that let you compute such arithmetic expressions. Shells are not intended to make such computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this part of the question isn't cleared yet, and not fine to post in a comment, I add this partial answer:

```
x=1; for i in 1 2 3 ; do x=$x+2; echo $x; done 
1+2
1+2+2
1+2+2+2
```

As a side note: Don't use exit 0 at the end of your script without a good reason. When the script is done, it exits by itself without your help. The exit status will be the exit status of the last command performed, in your case a simple echo, which will almost always succeed. In the rare cases it fails, you will probably without intention hide that failure.

If you source the script, the exit will throw you out of your running shell.

But you can rewrite your while loop like this:

```
x=0
while (($((x)) < 9)) 
do  
  echo x : $x
  x=$x+2
done
echo $((x))

x : 0
x : 0+2
x : 0+2+2
x : 0+2+2+2
x : 0+2+2+2+2
10
```

Comment: Thanks for the info and the partial answer.

Comment: So you mean to say the x=$x+2 is just string concatenation in bash, and not integer addition, as it would look.

Comment: Depends on who is looking :). Arithmetic expressions look like this in Bash: ((x+2)). Note that you omit the $ inside of ((x+2)). An `echo "$((1+2+2+2))"` would give you the expected result in the end. I add another code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

You get `line 9: 1=1+2: command not found` because `1=1+2` is what `$x=$x+2` is *expanded* into.

Use `expr` or `let` or `((...))` for integer calculations and `bc` for floating point:

```
let x=x+2
((x=x+2))           #same as above
((x+=2))            #same
((x++))             #if adding just one
((++x))             #if adding just one
x=$((x+2))
x=`expr $x + 2`     #space before and after +
x=$(echo $x+2|bc)   #using bc
x=$(echo $x+2.1|bc) #bc also works with floating points (numbers with decimals)
```

Comment: what about x=$x+2

Comment: [`((..))`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs) isn't the easiest feature to find in the manual. It does the same thing as `let`.

Comment: @YannVernier but you'll find out that `let` is never used by experimented people. It seems you haven't grasped the idioms of bash scripting yet.

Comment: You mean experienced, but shell scripters aren't so unified that this is a clear idiom. Personally, I'd rather see a script fail with `let: not found` than trying to execute `x=x+2` as an external command.

Comment: The [bash hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/let#examples) recommends the compound command over let, so I guess that'll stand as a style guide. The main reason would be to avoid `*` globbing.

Comment: POSIX shell does specify [arithmetic expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04), so the `x=$((x+2))` variant is the most portable of these next to the external `expr` call. It executes inside the shell even in dash or busybox ash, but is not [bash specific](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism). The `declare -i` variant is probably a winner in concise legibility.

Comment: @JohnDoe `x=1` then `x=$x+2` then `echo $x` will just output `1+2` not `3`.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's not the Bourne shell syntax for setting a variable; it looks more like Perl or PHP. The `$` is used for [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and is not part of the variable name. [Variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html#Shell-Parameters) assignment simply uses `=`, and [`let`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-let) evaluates arithmetic expressions (much like [`$((expression))`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html#Arithmetic-Expansion)). Another syntax that should work is `x=$((x+2))`. Note that these arithmetic evaluations are a bash feature; standard unix shells might require use of external tools such as `expr`.

Comment: It works, it just doesn't perform arithmetic evaluation (so breaks your `[ ]` test). [`declare -i`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-declare) can enable arithmetic evaluation for particular variables. Oddly, `test` claims it wants an expression but really expects just a number.

Comment: Please don't recommend `seq`. `seq` is non-standard and not idiomatic.

Comment: [`seq`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seq_%28Unix%29) is part of coreutils and likely to exist on GNU systems, but is not part of POSIX and is not included with some other unix variants. Removed the reference.