# How can I assign new value to a variable in a makefile after ignoring an error using ||

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, makefile

Lets say, I want to do something like this in my makefile.

```
myVar="Value1"

define compare_with_expect_file
    cat $(filePath1) | diff -c ${filePath2} || myVar+=$(myVar)
    echo $(myVar) // want it to be changed
endef
```

but this part does not work:

```
myVar+=$(myVar)
```

I am not able to change value of a variable that is placed after `||`

How can I make it work?

Comment: try \|\| like this.

Comment: thanx for the reply, but it does not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-to-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash try this for concat string

Comment: Your question is unclear. What value do you want the variable to have, and in what circumstances?

Comment: when there is an error in the line, I want to change value of $myVar. Value of variable can be different, I does not metter in this case. The problem is that it is not possible to change value of variable at all