# How to include dashes in the format string of bash printf?

Tags: bash, printf

I'm trying to concatenate strings in bash using `printf` by following [the examples here](https://linuxconfig.org/bash-printf-syntax-basics-with-examples):

```
$ printf "%s " "hello printf" "in" "bash script"
```

The above works. But when I try to add to the format string some dashes (`-`):

```
$ printf "--file=%s " "hello printf" "in" "bash script"
```

it generates an error:

> sh: printf: --: invalid option

Obviously, it's treating the format string as an option. How can I include dashes `-` into the output?

(I tried to add use `\-` to escape the dashes, to no avail.)

Comment: Why not using [string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-to-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Always specify end of command line flags when using strings involving `--`. In general the shell commands need to know where their positional argument start at. So by forcing `--` after `printf` we let it know that the subsequent arguments are to be interpreted as its arguments. At this point, afterwards using `--` will be treated literally instead of being considered as a command line switch.

so define your `printf` as

```
printf -- "--file=%s " "hello printf" "in" "bash script"
```

Also if you are planning to specify multiple `printf` argument strings,do not include them in same format specifier. You might need this

```
printf -- "--file=%s %s %s" "hello printf" "in" "bash script"
```

See more on [The printf command in bash](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf#the_printf_command)

Comment: The single `%s` is intentional, I'm guessing. `printf` will repeat the format string if there are extra arguments. `"--file=%s "  a b c` produces `--file=a --file=b --file=c`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: Yeah I wasn't sure, that's why include a word _might need_ to it.

Comment: Given the arguments in the example, it's far more likely the OP wants `for f in "hello printf" "in" "bash script"; do args+=(--file "$f")` rather than `printf` at all.

Comment: Good point. `"--file=%q "` would also work. Though an array is better.