# How to add certain words or word parts to copy names of a file using bash script?

Tags: bash

To be specific, the task is to make a bash shell program that recieves a file and makes a directory that has the same name as the file with the addition of "cop" and then stores a copy of the file inside that directory.

e.g. if the file is named test, the directory name would be testcop.

What command do I use for the purpose of adding letters to the name of a file whose name is based on the name of another file?

Comment: `mkdir` will make a directory. Is that what you want? Like `mkdir "$1cop" && cp "$1" "$1cop\"` or something like that

Comment: And for string concatenation, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-to-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash

Comment: yes, concatenation that's exactly what I needed, Thank you.