# concat strings of file cat in bash script

Tags: bash, unix, directory

I'm modifying this recursive directory crawling script from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/494143/recursive-shell-script-to-list-files

my plan is just to concatenate strings of the output of text files in my directory

so like: content+= content + cat file.txt, I feel like what I have isn't too far off but right now the output is blank and I guess I'm misunderstanding how to separate the cat function from the string concat portion

I tried using less instead of cat but that produces the same result I'm following the link below but none of the examples seem to produce an output for me
[How to concatenate string variables in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-to-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash)

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "starting script"
content="start =>"

walk_dir () {    
    shopt -s nullglob dotglob

    for pathname in "$1"/*; do
        if [ -d "$pathname" ]; then
            walk_dir "$pathname"
        else
            case "$pathname" in
                *.txt|*.doc)
                    #printf '%s\n' "$pathname"
                    content+=(cat "$pathname") #add file contents to the previous string
                
            esac
        fi
    done
    echo "$content"

}
DIR=/c/Users/xxxx/Desktop/xxxx

walk_dir "$DIR"
```

pretty new to bash scripting but

Answer (score 1):

Had a quick look - I think you are missing the $ sign in concat.

```
content+=$(cat "$pathname")
```

Alternatively, you can use backquote instead of parentheses without $.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to say `content+="$(cat "$pathname")"` to append the
output of `cat` to the scalar variable `content`.
Or you can just say:

```
shopt -s extglob globstar
content="$(cat **/*@(.txt|.doc))"
echo "$content"
```

to concatenate the contents of the text/document files recursively.