# Setting path of a given directory in a variable and referring to it in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I have a script which has some test cases in a directory

```
/home/raulp/testpackage/Scripts/engineTest/functionalTest/testX"
```

I have another package which initiates this script with the above path,
how can I universally set the path to it in a variable and refer it , somethignlike this

```
set SCRIPT_PATH='/home/raulp/testpackage/Scripts'
```

**UPDATE:**

ok got it, I got it from export SCRIPT_PATH = $PWD  ,

but now how can I combine (add) SCRIPT_PATH with another path?

export PATH! = $SCRIPT_PATH + "/my-another-path/my-another-directory/

Comment: You are looking for export command of bash. https://linuxhint.com/exporting-bash-variables/

Comment: ok got it, I got it from export SCRIPT_PATH = $PWD  , but how can I combine (add) SCRIPT_PATH with another path?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-to-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash