# Escaping Special Characters in Joined Path

Tags: bash, sh

Currently I have a bash script with `cd $PATH_TO_BUILD` where `PATH_TO_BUILD=$(pwd)/develop/build`. The pwd does have a space in the name and is causing the error however I can't seem to escape this with double quotes. Even if I do `PATH_TO_BUILD="$(pwd)"/develop/build` or put the $pwd in a different variable before I still get the error. How can I get around this?

Comment: Is your script using `cd $PATH_TO_BUILD` (missing the `$` in your question), perhaps, and it should be using `cd "$PATH_TO_BUILD"`?

Comment: Yes sorry typo will edit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate string variables in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-to-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash)