# Piping stdin to a cURL header

Tags: curl, pipe, keycloak, zsh, jq

I am trying to read get an authentication token from a Keycloak endpoint and use it to access another resource. Getting the token is not an issue, but passing it along in the header of another request is turning out to be an impossible feat, at least in a single command:

```
curl \
    -X POST \
    -d 'client_id=app' \
    -d 'username=username' \
    -d 'password=password' \
    -d 'grant_type=password' \
    -d "client_secret=$APP_SECRET" \
    'http://localhost:9000/auth/realms/realm/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
| \
jq -r '.access_token' \
| \
curl \
    -X GET \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer @-" \ # <- read header value from stdin
    -u "username:password" \
    "http://localhost:8080/app/api/"
```

What might be an alternative way of achieving this?

Comment: This might help: `echo def | echo "abc$(</dev/stdin)ghi"`

Comment: @Cyrus Somewhat: echo 123 | echo "abc $(</dev/stdin) def"
zsh: error when reading /dev/stdin: Input/output error
abc  def

Comment: Replaced the tag "bash" with "zsh". Hope that helps.

Comment: Why not simply do this in two steps? extract the token, store in variable and re-use it in next `curl`?

Comment: Because I'm bad at shell scripting. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creating a *complex* command, why not split it into 2 actions:

1. [Save the token to a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354943/setting-jq-output-to-a-bash-variable)
2. [Pass the variable to the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-to-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash)

---

```sh
# Get token
token=$(curl \
    -X POST \
    -d 'client_id=app' \
    -d 'username=username' \
    -d 'password=password' \
    -d 'grant_type=password' \
    -d "client_secret=$APP_SECRET" \
    'http://localhost:9000/auth/realms/realm/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
| jq -r '.access_token')

# Send request
curl \
    -X GET \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
    -u "username:password" \
    "http://localhost:8080/app/api/"
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer provides a better solution, but this post answers the literal question asked.

You can use the following:

```sh
"Authorization: Bearer $( cat )"
```

Demo:

```sh
$ echo foo | printf "%s\n" "Authorization: Bearer $( cat )"
Authorization: Bearer foo
```

In fact, you could put the entire token-fetching code inside of `$()`.

```sh
curl                              \
    -X GET                        \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(
        curl                               \
            -X POST                        \
            -d "client_id=app"             \
            -d "username=username"         \
            -d "password=password"         \
            -d "grant_type=password"       \
            -d "client_secret=$APP_SECRET" \
            "http://localhost:9000/auth/realms/realm/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
        | jq -r .access_token
    )"                            \
    -u "username:password"        \
    "http://localhost:8080/app/api/"
```

Demo:

```sh
$ printf "%s\n" "Authorization: Bearer $( echo foo )"
Authorization: Bearer foo
```

Again, I consider these inferior to the clearer solution provided by @0stone0. I am posting them for educational purposes.