# Manipulating content of a variable argument in bash

Tags: bash

I'm a beginner at bash. There are a lot of similar question to that question, but I didn't manage to find one addressing that specific situation.

The concatenating problem is just an imaginary context to illustrate the real issue, which is:   Bash functions can only return integers between 0 and 255. Please don't comment "bash can concatenate strings natively using x command" that's not the core of my issues.

I came up with a "workaround" for that problem, using an auxiliary variable for storing the string result of a function that needs to return a string.

```sh
function concatenate(){
    echo "Arg1: $1 Arg2: $2 Arg3: $3"
    $1="$1$2$3"
}

result="a"
concatenate "$result" "hello" " world!"

echo $result
```

`$1` is a reference to the first argument (`result` variable). `$2`, a reference to the second argument. `$3`, third argument.

I think I managed to pass the arguments I wanted to the function, as `echo` printed them correctly. However I'm not managing to change `$1`, `result` value, it throws an error.

```
Arg1: a Arg2: hello Arg3:  world!
main.bash: line 8: a:=ahello world!: command not found
a
```

I also tried the `+=` syntax as proposed here: [How to concatenate string variables in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-to-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash)

```
function concatenate(){
    echo "Arg1: $1 Arg2: $2 Arg3: $3"
    $1+=$2
    $1+=$3
}

result="a"
concatenate "$result" "hello" " world!"

echo $result
```

But the error still persists:

```
Arg1: a Arg2: hello Arg3:  world!
main.bash: line 8: a+=hello: command not found
main.bash: line 9: a+=: command not found
a
```

I know many languages have an issue with changing an argument locally not changing it globally. I'm not sure if I'm using the wrong syntax, or if that's the case.

Could someone please help me? I would welcome very much if it's not the case my workaround is the proper for dealing with that kind of situation, and if someone can tell the proper one. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bash version is 4.3 or newer, you can use **nameref**s:

```
concatenate() { declare -n ref=$1; ref=$2$3; }

concatenate result "hello" " world!"
echo "$result"
```

And this version will concatenate any number of arguments:

```
concatenate() { local -n ref=$1; local IFS=""; ref=${*:2}; }

concatenate result "This" " version" " concatenates" " any" " number" " of" " arguments"
echo "$result"
```

Another trick is to use the `-v` option of `printf` (requires bash 3.1 or higher):

```
concatenate() { printf -v "$1" '%s' "${@:2}"; }
```

This will paste all arguments beginning from the second argument (the first is the variable name to be assigned)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll change the accepted answer to that one since it's more versatile, making the variable a reference makes it straightforward to solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `eval` to execute an assignment with a dynamic variable.

And to get the old value of `$a`, you need to use an indirect variable: `${!1}`

```
concatenate() {
    echo "Arg1: $1 Arg2: $2 Arg3: $3"
    eval "$1='${!1}$2$3'"
}
```

And when you call the function, you need to provide the name of the result variable literally:

```
concatenate result "hello" " world!"
```

P.S. There's no good reason to use the bash-specific `function` keyword. Use the standard function definition syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Also for describing the names of the syntaxes  (dynamic variables assignment, indirect variables), it will definitely help me when studying. I'll accept the answer as soon as stack lets me

Comment: Hey @barmar the error is no long being thrown but the assignment is not working yet, `result` is `a`

Comment: You're passing the value of the result variable instead of the name. I've updated the answer.

Comment: It's working, thank you very much!