# Head & tail string in one line - possible?

Tags: bash

I want to retrieve the first X and the last Y characters from a string (standard ascii, so no worries about unicode).

I understand that I can do this as seperate actions, i.e. :

```
FIRST=$(echo foobar | head -c 3)
LAST=$(echo foobar | tail -c 3)
COMBINED= "${FIRST}${LAST}"
```

But is there a cleaner way to do this ?

I would prefer to use common standard utils (i.e. bash built-ins, sed, awk etc.).  At a push, a Perl one-liner is OK, but no Python or anything else.

Comment: `combined=${foobar:0:3}${foobar: -3:3}` uses the bash parameter expansions for string-indexing to combine the first and last `3` characters of `foobar` (note: the `space` before `" -3"` is required for offset from the end of the string -- or put it in parenthesis `(-3)`). Don't use `ALLCAPS` variable names, those are reserved for environment variables and bash internal variables (like `BASH_REMATCH`) Example `a=foobar; echo "${a: -3}${a:0:3}"` results in `barfoo` output.

Comment: That's very cool @DavidC.Rankin I clearly need to up my game on bash parameter expansions !

Comment: They are incredibly capable. Just see [man 1 bash](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) and scroll down to the heading `"Parameter Expansion"` (if you search it, it's about the 4th find down) You can slice and dice any string you need. The benefit -- they are bash-builtins, so there is no wasted spawning of separate subshells calling linux utilities.

Comment: As an aside, the space after the equals sign is an error, and [don't use upper case for your private variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization); see also https://shellcheck.net/ which can diagnose many beginner bugs and antipatterns.

Answer (score 3):

## `head` + `tail` two answers, regarding `-c` switch

### 1. `head` + `tail` *character based* (with `-c`, reducing *strings*)

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could

```
string=foobarbaz
echo ${string::3}${string: -3}
foobaz
```

But to avoid repetion in case of shorter strings:

```
if ((${#string}>6));then
    echo ${string::3}${string: -3}
else
    echo $string
fi
```

#### Full [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) function

```
shrinkStr(){
    local sep='..' opt OPTIND OPTARG string varname='' paddstr paddchr=' '
    local -i maxlen=40 lhlen=15 rhlen padd=0
    while getopts 'P:l:m:s:v:p' opt; do
        case $opt in 
            l) lhlen=$OPTARG ;;
            m) maxlen=$OPTARG ;;
            p) padd=1 ;;
            P) paddchr=$OPTARG ;;
            s) sep=$OPTARG ;;
            v) varname=$OPTARG ;;
            *) echo Wrong arg.; return 1 ;;
        esac
    done
    rhlen="maxlen-lhlen-${#sep}"
    ((rhlen<1)) && { echo bad lengths; return 1;}
    shift $((OPTIND-1))
    string="$*"
    if ((${#string}>maxlen)) ;then
        string="${string::lhlen}$sep${string: -rhlen}"
    elif ((${#string}<maxlen)) && ((padd));then
        printf -v paddstr '%*s' $((maxlen-${#string})) ''
        string+=${paddstr// /$paddchr}
    fi
    if [[ $varname ]] ;then
        printf -v "$varname" '%s' "$string"
    else
        echo "$string"
    fi
}
```

Then

```
shrinkStr -l 4 -m 10 Hello world!
Hell..rld!

shrinkStr -l 2 -m 10 Hello world!
He..world!

shrinkStr -l 3 -m 10 -s '+++' Hello world!
Hel+++rld!
```

#### This work even with UTF-8 characters:

```
cnt=1;for str in Généralités Language Théorème Février 'Hello world!';do
    shrinkStr -l5 -m11 -vOutstr -pP_ "$str"
    printf '  %11d:  |%s|\n' $((cnt++)) "$Outstr"
done
            1:  |Généralités|
            2:  |Language___|
            3:  |Théorème___|
            4:  |Février____|
            5:  |Hello..rld!|

cnt=1;for str in Généralités Language Théorème Février 'Hello world!';do
    shrinkStr -l5 -m10 -vOutstr -pP_ "$str"
    printf '  %11d:  |%s|\n' $((cnt++)) "$Outstr"
done
            1:  |Génér..tés|
            2:  |Language__|
            3:  |Théorème__|
            4:  |Février___|
            5:  |Hello..ld!|
```

### 2. `head` + `tail` *lines based* (without `-c`, reducing *files*)

By using only one *fork* to `sed`.

Here is a little function I wrote for this:

```
headTail() {
    local hln=${1:-10} tln=${2:-10} str;
    printf -v str '%*s' $((tln-1)) '';
    sed -ne "1,${hln}{p;\$q};$((hln+1)){${str// /\$!N;}};:a;\$!{N;D;ba};p"
}
```

Usage:

```
headTail <head lines> <tail lines>
```

Both argument default are *`10`*.

In practice:

```
headTail 3 4 < <(seq 1 1000)
1
2
3
997
998
999
1000
```

Seem correct. Testing border case (where number of line are smaller than requested):

```
headTail 1 9 < <(seq 1 3)
1
2
3
headTail 9 1 < <(seq 1 3)
1
2
3
```

Taking more lines: (I will **take 100 first and 100 last lines**, but print only 2 **T**op lines, 4 **M**iddle lines and 2 **B**ottom lines of `headTail`'s output.):

```
headTail 100 100 < <(seq 1 2000)|sed -ne '1,2s/^/T /p;99,102s/^/M /p;199,$s/^/B /p'
T 1
T 2
M 99
M 100
M 1901
M 1902
B 1999
B 2000
```

**BUG** (limit): Don't use this with `0` as argument!

```
headTail 0 3 < <(seq 1 2000) 
1
1998
1999
2000
headTail 3 0 < <(seq 1 2000) 
1
2
3
1999
2000
```

**BUG** (limit): because of *max line length*:

> ```
> headTail 4 32762 <<<Foo\ bar
> bash: /bin/sed: Argument list too long
> ```

For both this to be supported, function would become:

#### `head` + `tail` *lines*, using one fork to `sed`

```
headTail() {
    local hln=${1:-10} tln=${2:-10} str sedcmd=''
    ((hln>0)) && sedcmd+="1,${hln}{p;\$q};"
    if ((tln>0)) ;then
        printf -v str '%*s' $((tln-1)) ''
        sedcmd+="$((hln+1)){${str// /\$!N;}};:a;\$!{N;D;ba};p;"
    fi
    sed -nf <(echo "$sedcmd")
}
```

Then

```
headTail 3 4 < <(seq 1 1000) |xargs
1 2 3 997 998 999 1000
headTail 3 0 < <(seq 1 1000) |xargs
1 2 3
headTail 0 4 < <(seq 1 1000) |xargs
997 998 999 1000

for i in {6..9};do printf " %3d: " $i;headTail 3 4 < <(seq 1 $i) |xargs; done
   6: 1 2 3 4 5 6
   7: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
   8: 1 2 3 5 6 7 8
   9: 1 2 3 6 7 8 9
```

**Stronger test:** With bigger numbers: Reading 500'000 first and 500'000 last lines from an input of 3'000'000 lines:

```
headTail 500000 500000 < <(seq 1 3000000) | sed -ne '499999,500002p'
499999
500000
2500001
2500002

headTail 5000000 5000000 < <(seq 1 30000000) | sed -ne '4999999,5000002p'
4999999
5000000
25000001
25000002
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
$ perl -E '($s, $x, $y) = @ARGV; substr $s, $x, -$y, ""; say $s' abcdefgh 2 3
abfgh
```

The four argument variant of [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr) replaces the given portion of the string with the last argument. Here, we replace from position $x to position -$y (negative numbers count from the end of the string), and use an empty string as replacement, i.e. we remove the middle part.