# Bash Variable cannot work to get current time

Tags: bash, date, variables

I write a very simple script to get the current time and display it, as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

CurrentTime = "date +%F-%H-%M-%S"
echo "Archive logs at ${CurrentTime}..."
```

I refer articles like this [How to concatenate string variables in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-to-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash)

But it does not work, when executing, it will output the following:

```
./test.sh: line 3: CurrentTime: command not found
Archive logs at ...
```

Why?

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: @Cyrus, Thank you. That is a great tool!

Comment: _Why?_ : If you write a command line `A B C D`, the first word (`A`) is taken as a program to be executed, and the remaining words are the parameters to the programm. Hence `CurrentTime = something` tries to run a program named _CurrentTime_ with `=` and `something` as parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this

```bash
CurrentTime=$(date +%F-%H-%M-%S)
echo "Archive logs at ${CurrentTime}..."
```

If you surround the equal sign with spaces, then it is likely to be interpreted as an argument for command `CurrentTime` (that does not exist).