# bash script repeating an element

Tags: bash

I am writing a shell script to run a terminal command 10 times with the section "mid" repeating for i in [1, 10].

```
intro="0:R:1:6,0:R:1:7,0:R:1:8,0:R:1:9,0:R:1:10,0:R:1:11,0:R:1:12,0:R:1:13,0:R:1:14,0.5:R:1:15,"
mid="0:r:1:0,0:b:1:0,0:s:1:0,0:v:1:0,0:h:1:0,0:r:1:0,0:b:1:0,0:s:1:0,0:v:1:0,0:h:1:0,\
0:r:1:1,0:b:1:1,0:s:1:1,0:v:1:1,0:h:1:1,0:r:1:1,0:b:1:1,0:s:1:1,0:v:1:1,0:h:1:1,\
0:r:1:2,0:b:1:2,0:s:1:2,0:v:1:2,0:h:1:2,0:r:1:2,0:b:1:2,0:s:1:2,0:v:1:2,0:h:1:2,\
0:r:1:3,0:b:1:3,0:s:1:3,0:v:1:3,0:h:1:3,0:r:1:3,0:b:1:3,0:s:1:3,0:v:1:3,0:h:1:3,\
0:r:1:4,0:b:1:4,0:s:1:4,0:v:1:4,0:h:1:4,0:r:1:4,0:b:1:4,0:s:1:4,0:v:1:4,0:h:1:4,\
0:r:1:5,0:b:1:5,0:s:1:5,0:v:1:5,0:h:1:5,0:r:1:5,0:b:1:5,0:s:1:5,0:v:1:5,0:h:1:5,\
0:r:1:6,0:b:1:6,0:s:1:6,0:v:1:6,0:h:1:6,0:r:1:6,0:b:1:6,0:s:1:6,0:v:1:6,0:h:1:6,\
0:r:1:7,0:b:1:7,0:s:1:7,0:v:1:7,0:h:1:7,0:r:1:7,0:b:1:7,0:s:1:7,0:v:1:7,0:h:1:7,\
0:r:1:8,0:b:1:8,0:s:1:8,0:v:1:8,0:h:1:8,0:r:1:8,0:b:1:8,0:s:1:8,0:v:1:8,0:h:1:8,\
0:r:1:9,0:b:1:9,0:s:1:9,0:v:1:9,0:h:1:9,0:r:1:9,0:b:1:9,0:s:1:9,0:v:1:9,0:h:1:9,"
outro="0:T:1:0,0:T:1:1,0:T:1:2,0:T:1:3,0:T:1:4,0:T:1:5,0:T:1:6,0:T:1:7,0:T:1:8,0:R:1:9"

touch ../eval/"times.txt"
for i in {1..10}
do
    # concatenate intro, mid (repeated i times), and outro
    echo "starting requst $i"
    script="${intro}${mid}${outro}"
    # run terminal command with script
    /usr/bin/time -v ./server_mimg -q 1500 -w 1 -p FIFO 2222 & ./client 2222 -I ./images/ -L "${script}" >> ../eval/times.txt
    # wait for script to be done running
    wait
    echo "request $i complete"
done
```

I specifically need help with the line

```
    script="${intro}${mid}${outro}"
```

as I am not sure how I should get the mid section to repeat *i* times in every iteration. Any other outstanding syntax errors caught would be much appreciated!

Comment: if you're generating sytnax errors consider cutting-n-pasting your code (along with appropriate shebang) into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and make the recommended changes

Comment: consider reviewing [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then come back and update the question; in particular *a)* reduce the volume of data in the 3x variables to that which adequately demonstrates the requirement *b)* reduce the code to the bare minimum needed to demonstrate the issue (eg, we likely don't need the `server_ming` invocation cluttering up the the code) and *c)* include both the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output

Comment: There's no point in using `wait`. That's for waiting for background commands to finish, but you aren't running anything in the background. The shell always waits for foreground commands.

Comment: `{1..10}` is **only** bash syntax, not valid in sh. Why is this question tagged sh when you're using code sh can't run?

Comment: `mid` is currently defined as 10 (concatenated) lines of input with the only difference in the 10 lines being the use of numbers 0-9; is your intention to use ***one*** of these 10 lines for each pass through the loop? is it your intention that `{1..10}` is mapped to `{0..9}`? you could reduce the level of confusion by  *a)* using a smaller representative data set and *b)* showing the desired contents of the variable `script` for the first couple passes through the loop

Comment: please verify/confirm the last entries for the `intro` and `outro` variables; should [intro] `0.5:R:1:15,` be `0:R:1:15,`? should [outro] `0:R:1:9` be `0:T:1:9`? also, do you want the `intro` sections to be numbered `{6..15}` or `{0..9}` as is the case for the `outro` variable?

Comment: @markp-fuso Yes:   `printf -v intro '0:R:1:%d,' {6..14};intro+='0.5:R:1:15,'` is shorter than `intro="0:R:1:6,0:R:1:7,0:R:1:8,0:R:1:9,0:R:1:10,0:R:1:11,0:R:1:12,0:R:1:13,0:R:1:14,0.5:R:1:15,"` !  (and not less readable ;-)

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub my question wasn't about readability but about the actual values on the end of those 2 variables; typos or intentional?  if that's a typo re: `intro` then `printf -v intro "0:R:1:%d,' {6..15}` is shorter and (imo) very much readable *and* less prone to typos; depending on OP's response on how to use `mid` then an additional `printf -v` would be preferable to 10 lines of manually entered (with possible typos) data

Comment: @markp-fuso Yes, but using this syntax answer the question; if a typo: use you're syntax, if not, then use mine! This is more easy to read!

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub I think we're on the same sheet of music; I may have misread your double negative - `(and not less readable)` == `(more readable)` ?  :-)

Comment: @markp-fuso You're not wrong! "Not less" could mean something like "more" ;-)

Comment: Sorry for all the errors everyone... I'm not an expert in sh or bash and got confused. Thank you for the advice on syntax. Unfortunately, I was writing script to automate sets of server runs for an assignment and the intro, mid, and outro variables were given by my professor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the repeated portion gets longer by one `$mid` every time, one way to do what you want is to keep the repeated portion in a variable and add to it every time through the loop.  This skeleton code demonstrates the idea:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

# ...

repeated_mid=''
for i in {1..10}; do
    # ...
    repeated_mid+=$mid
    script="${intro}${repeated_mid}${outro}"
    # ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested loop that concatenates `$mid` the required number of times.

```
for i in {1..10}
do
    # concatenate intro, mid (repeated i times), and outro
    echo "starting requst $i"
    script="$intro"
    for ((x = 0; x < i; x++)); do
        script+="$mid"
    done
    script+="$outro"
    # run terminal command with script
    /usr/bin/time -v ./server_mimg -q 1500 -w 1 -p FIFO 2222 & ./client 2222 -I ./images/ -L "${script}" >> ../eval/times.txt
    echo "request $i complete"
done
```

Note that this script uses a number of `bash` extensions: range expressions in braces, arithmetic expressions in the `for` loop, and `+=` concatenation. It won't work as written in `sh`.

Comment: For this you could use [`+=` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18041780/1765658): `script=${intro}`, then `script+=${mid}`, and finally: `script+=${outro}`.

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer and added a note about all the non-`sh` syntax in the script.