# How can I get the resolution (width and height) for a video file in Nautilus/Caja linux file manager?

Tags: file, ubuntu, nautilus

I have read this
[How can I get the resolution (width and height) for a video file from a linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684015/how-can-i-get-the-resolution-width-and-height-for-a-video-file-from-a-linux-co) 
but that's for command line.

I would like to know how to get the video information in the file manager so I could sort by video size using the file manager GUI.

Attached is a screen shot showing the available options... video rez/size is NOT included.

I'm running Linux Mint 13. Maybe a script that runs in the background that pulls the vid. size info and pushes it to the file manager columns?

Here's the screen shot:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B19mmCKTPBRYV0FkLV9kc2JtRU0/edit?usp=sharing

thank you for your help,
Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MediaInfo http://mediainfo.sf.net has a command line version and provides the dimensions together with tons of other information.