# Get video resolution in nodejs

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, resolution

I have been trying to get an answer to this without really finding any. Excuse me if this sounds stupid or obvious.

I have a nodejs application and basically I would like to simply get the resolution of a video. Imagine I have film stored on disk and I would like to be able to know if it is in 720p or 1080p or anything else.

I understood that I might need to use ffmpeg to do so, but then I also understood that ffmpeg was mostly used to "record, convert and stream audio and video files".
That does not mean retrieve video resolution.

Thank you for your help

Edit 1:
The node.js app is a desktop app and needs to be portable to Linux, windows and OS X. If possible a portable answer would be more appreciated but of course any answer is welcome.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To be honest I think the best method I found was to use [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) with ffprobe as you are able to set the the path to the executable. The only problem is that ffmpeg has to be shipped with the app. So different executables have to be shipped, one for each distribution/os/derivation. If anyone has anything better I am open to answers.

Getting the width, height and aspect ratio using fluent-ffmpeg is done like so:

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

ffmpeg.setFfprobePath(pathToFfprobeExecutable);

ffmpeg.ffprobe(pathToYourVideo, function(err, metadata) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        // metadata should contain 'width', 'height' and 'display_aspect_ratio'
        console.log(metadata);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have used this package for a while now and i noticed a bug with it,sometimes it switches video height and width. Use it at your own risk.

Comment: @ChidozieDuru is it possible that you are neglecting the "rotate" tag that results in the provided width and height values being reversed? Many videos are saved with the camera sensor's orientation and a rotation metadata tag similar to EXIF for images. For example, if I record a portrait video with my iPhone: ffprobe reports a landscape width and height (because that is how the sensor is oriented on the phone) and then includes a "rotation": "-90" field to indicate the intended orientation for viewing.

Comment: @willbattel i actually added it

Answer (score 8):

There's a `npm` package called [`get-video-dimensions`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-video-dimensions) that also use `ffprobe` and it's much easier to use. It also support promises and async/await.

```
import getDimensions from 'get-video-dimensions';
```

Using **promise**:

```
getDimensions('video.mp4').then(dimensions => {
  console.log(dimensions.width);
  console.log(dimensions.height);
})
```

or **async/await**:

```
const dimensions = await getDimensions('video.mp4');
console.log(dimensions.width);
console.log(dimensions.height);
```

Answer (score 3):

I use node-ffprobe to accomplish this for images:

```
var probe = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/node-ffprobe');
probe(filePath, function (err, data) {
    //the 'data' variable contains the information about the media file
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**fileMetaData** will have width, height, codec info, aspect ratio etc ...

```
const ffprobe = require('ffprobe')
const ffprobeStatic = require('ffprobe-static')
const fileMetaData = await ffprobe(fileName, { path: ffprobeStatic.path })
```

> fileName could be video('webm', 'mov', 'wmv', 'mpg', 'mpeg', 'mp4','flv' etc..) or image(jpg, gif, png etc..) path. 
>   fileName example: /path/to/video.mp4  or http://example.com/video.mp4

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to to run another application as a child process, and get the resolution from std out. I'm not aware of any pure node.js solution for this.

See `child_process.exec` https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

and `ffprobe`
[How can I get the resolution (width and height) for a video file from a linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684015/how-can-i-get-the-resolution-width-and-height-for-a-video-file-from-a-linux-co)

Comment: That might be good although I don't know about portability as ffmpeg needs to be installed on the host's machine and that might be difficult. I'll give it a try I let you know

Comment: Yea, you might be able to distribute the binary with your app if you know your deployment environments.

Comment: Yes that would be the best idea. It would mostly be OSX, Linux (Debian, FreeBSD) and windows