# How to determine dimension (=resolution, =height and width) or a video file on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, video, command-line, resolution

Is there a way to determine the height and width of a video file under Mac OS X? I have a project im Python where I write something like a media management program similar to iTunes. I would rather read the dimensions of the video file directly from the file itself. The alternative for me would be to ask the user, but this is of course a bad user experience.

I don't know if there is a way to do this in python. One idea of mine is to call a system command `ret = os.system("getVideoResolution " + filename)`, but I have not found one that finds the video resolution.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I apologize for my bad manners. I revised the question.

Comment: Dear future self: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684015/how-can-i-get-the-resolution-width-and-height-for-a-video-file-from-a-linux-co